# When someone answers their own question in an edit?

Tags: discussion, questions

So today I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430050/how-to-override-css-box-sizing-for-just-one-area-on-page) that the user ended up finding their own answer to. The problem is that they answered it in an edit on the question instead of posting an answer. Is there anything we can do as a community to fix this for future users to see that there may be an answer, instead of them skimming over the question seeing as there were no answers posted or accepted?

This one in particular bothers me because when I search the twitter-bootstrap tag I want to find unanswered questions so I can help people; and while this question is close to the top of that search, there is nothing to add to the post.

It is a post asked 8 months ago and another user already commented on it to post the answer as an answer, but the user has not responded.

Comment: There's a dupe of this lying around somewhere but I can't find it at the moment. Essentially: rollback the edit so that the answer isn't included anymore, then leave a comment for the user to post it as an answer instead (but a 4k user *should* have known better...). If they don't, post it yourself as a community wiki after a day or two, or just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

Post a comment asking the OP to post their answer.  Wait a few days.  If they don't respond or comply, then post their edit as an answer with a note that the OP was asked to post it but they never did.  This way, you're covering your bases and also allowing someone to see the answer where it should show up.

Comment: A different user asked the OP a week ago and the OP did not respond. I just posted again to remind them. How long would I wait?

Comment: Please also mark it "community wiki", as it is not really your answer, but theirs transplanted.

Comment: @JordanD I'd say a week is more than enough, post it as a wiki and rollback the question.

Comment: If they haven't responded in a week, they're probably not going to respond.  It's probably safe to post it as an answer, just make sure you explain why you're doing it so people don't downvote you thinking you're trying to swipe rep.

Comment: Making the answer Community Wiki will prevent any reputation changes from votes.

Comment: Actually, post it immediately. THough you might want to add a comment that if the OP wants to post it himself, you will delete that CW post.

Comment: @Deduplicator , he only posted code with no real explanation. Should I just c&p code as a cw?

Comment: Possibly credit Josh Crozier as it looks like he actually suggested the fix in a comment

Comment: In that case, follow deceze answer on the dup-target: A nod to the OP for providing the idea (Or as JonK says to whoever else gave that), as much of the code he provided as makes sense, and make a good answer out of it with an explanation and maybe more code. In that case, it is definitely your answer, so no CW.